# How to keep the terminal from scrolling

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am writing a simple program in C++ to be run in a terminal window. I would like the output text to be locked in position on the screen. Instead of each new line appearing at the bottom of the screen and pushing everything up, I would like to be able to change a line of text or some characters in a line of text, while keeping other lines above and below it static. I know I have seen this done in terminal, and I believe it was done with C++, but I can't find any documentation on it. I cannot even think of what this type of display might be called. My google fu has failed me; please help. If you can tell me what commands/library to use, that would be great, but even being able to tell me what commands accomplish this in a programming language other than C++ would give me more to go on than I have now.

Comment: This stuff really doesn't have much to do with C++.

Answer (score 6):

You want `ncurses`, a library for displaying text on a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming for Microsoft Windows, try [googling](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=win32+console+functions) for [Win32 Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).